# Question about rendered mode

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm relatively new to Blender and while working on a project in version 2.81a, I attempted to look at my render in render mode by pressing "z" and then "rendered". However, when I did this, the render became greyed out and could barely be seen. I added a light to the scene as well as a camera but nothing helped. What can I do to fix the greyness?

Pics:

[image]
Rendered mode

[image]
Solid mode

Additional info: Running on a titan X graphics card, with a very capable CPU. Both the cup and plate have materials but when I removed them they looked the same.

Edit: full screen while in rendered mode
[image]

Edit 2: more powerful point light
[image]

Comment: Could you add a picture showing the entire Blender window?

Comment: Yes, updated the post just now.

Comment: I would guess that you need to significantly increase the power of the point light for your scene to become visible.

Comment: @stphnl329 I tried that but it is still fairly gray, I'll add another edit to show what it looks like now.

Comment: I take it you're using the *Eevee* render engine? Go to the *Render Properties* tab and enable *Screen Space Reflections*, and within that menu, *Refraction.* You could also switch to the *Cycles* render engine. I take it that you're working on a cup for the Donut tutorial, so using *Cycles* may be beneficial for now.

Comment: @stphnl329 That fixed my problem! Thank you so much!